# Find Instance of String(s) with space in between within larger string PHP

Tags: php, regex, search, substring

I would like to be able to find the number of occurrences of a specific string within a larger string.

For example take the following...

```
$body = "I love My Dog. I love My cat. What a cat."
$count = substr_count($body, "My cat");
```

Say I am searching for My Cat. First I want to find all occurrences of "My Cat", once I have that I want to find all occurrences of "My" then "cat", to do this I run the substring count again but change the needle. The issue is that so many words contain cat and substring count returns all of those. I have the following regex

```
if (preg_match('/\\b' . "My cat" . '\\b/', $body)) {
```

but I am unsure of how to search an entire String and find the number of occurrences without breaking it up into an array (which could be tough seeing as I search for "My cat" in addition to the individual terms so breaking it up by spaces wouldn't work.

Is there a way to use substring_count or a similar function to find number of occurrences of individual terms that aren't part of another word.

Ideally in the end I want

```
"My cat" : count 1
"My": count 2
"cat": count 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you not want `"My" : count 2`?

Comment: Sorry about that, made the edit. Thanks

Comment: Can `"My cat"` contain more than two words? Or are you always searching for one or two words?

Comment: Yes, "My cat" could be "what a great day", just was using "my cat" as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
<?
$body = "I love My Dog. I love My cat. What a cat.";

$search = "My cat";

// Find full string matches
preg_match_all("/[^a-zA-Z]".$search."[^a-zA-Z]/i",$body,$matches);
$found[$search] = count($matches[0]);

// Find individual terms
$search = explode(" ",$search);
foreach($search as $term) {
    preg_match_all("/[^a-zA-Z]".$term."[^a-zA-Z]/i",$body,$matches);
    $found[$term] = count($matches[0]);
}

// Print results
foreach($found as $term=>$count) {
    echo '"'.$term.'": count '.$count."\n";
}
?>
```

outputs:

```
"My cat": count 1
"My": count 2
"cat": count 2
```